# How to add gitignore file through Github for Mac app

Tags: macos, github, osx-mavericks

I want to set a run in a gitignore in Github for Mac. My rule? `game/bin/*`, which `*` I hope means `all`. How would I add such a rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a file named `.gitignore` in your project folder and *Github for Mac* and all other git programs will ignore the mentioned files. Details [on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) and [in the official git docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).